# Searchkick not returning any results in RSpec

Tags: elasticsearch, rspec, searchkick

I'm trying to test a class with RSpec which makes use of Searchkick.

I have the following in my spec support directory:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # Reindex models
    Restaurant.reindex
    # and disable callbacks
    Searchkick.disable_callbacks
  end

  config.around(:each, search: true) do |example|
    Searchkick.callbacks(true) do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

and my test looks like this:

```
describe Restaurants::SearchFacade, search: true do
  subject { described_class }

  describe '#search' do
    context 'with a query' do
      let!(:restaurant_1) { create(:restaurant, :reindex, description: 'Amazing sour dough pizza place') }
      let!(:restaurant_2) { create(:restaurant, :reindex) }

      it 'returns values containing the query' do
        Restaurant.search_index.refresh
        params = { search: { query: 'sour dough' } }
        facade = subject.new(params)

        expect(facade.search.total_count).to eq(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I should be receiving 1 result. However, Searchkick returns 0 results. This is not a problem with the facade since I've also tried with `Restaurant.search('*')` which should return all results but nothing is being returned.

My Restaurant class looks like this:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick searchable: %i[title description street_address]
end
```

and my factory looks something like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :restaurant do
    association :plan
    association :company
    sequence :title do |n|
      "Restaurant #{n}"
    end
    description 'An awesome restaurant'
    # More attributes here...

    trait :reindex do
      after(:create) do |restaurant, _evaluator|
        restaurant.reindex(refresh: true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea what may be causing this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of all of that fancy stuff you are doing in your before(:suite) and your factories. You just need to be doing it before each spec (if the search tag is set).

I was able to get searchkick working with rspec and indexing my models with only this small amount of code in my spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.before(:each) do |example|
      # Elasticsearch / Searchkick
      if example.metadata[:search]
         Searchkick.enable_callbacks
         Restaurant.reindex
      else
         Searchkick.disable_callbacks
      end
   end
end
```

Side note: You may still need to run the `Restaurant.search_index.refresh` code after creating a bunch of Restaurant records in your spec setup. I'm not entirely sure?